# PHP ^7.1 meaning

Tags: php, version, magento2.3.6

Just to make something clear, when my Magento 2 module state:

```
   "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.0"
},
```

Does that mean that the module support PHP version 7.1 and higher or only 7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question is not directly related to Magento, but I would like to answer.
Composer.json file uses mainly 3 symbols, i.e. tilde (~), caret (^),  wildcard ( * ).

Here is the difference:

First lets take a look at tilde (~) symbol:

```
~3.1.2 means >= 3.1.2,< 3.2.0,
~3.1   means >= 3.1.0,< 4.0.0,
~0.3   means >= 0.3.0,< 1.0.0,
~3     means >= 3.0.0,< 4.0.0.
```

The caret (^) symbol is a bit different:

```
^3.1.2 means >= 3.1.2,< 4.0.0,
^3.1   means >= 3.1.0,< 4.0.0 (just like ~3.1),
^0.3   means >= 0.2.0,< 0.4.0,
^3     means >= 3.0.0,<4.0.0 (As it is like ~3)
```

While wildcard ( * )  means value lies between 0 to 9

I hope it helped.

Comment: So when my Magento 3rd party says ^7.1.0 it will support our PHP version on Magento which is 7.3?

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna Yes - it will suport anything greater than 7.1 but less than 8.0. There is a useful website you can use to test it out here - https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/